# integrate Eclipse and arcanist

Tags: eclipse, phabricator

Arcanist is a part of code review tool of Phabricator. For some reasons, our developers don't like use commands to push code. Is that way to integrate ecplise(J2EE) and arcanist?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no official plugin to integrate arcanist or any other phabricator application data into eclipse yet.

But feel free to create a [feature request](https://secure.phabricator.com/maniphest/task/edit/form/2/) :)